# Complex Filter Criteria no Results

Tags: 8, views

I'm working on a views to show different events in a calendar. I want to be able to filter on terms (In my view the field is called 'Wat?' for terms like music, art, design, etc). For this I create a filter criteria with an exposed filter for these taxonomy terms.

When I filter on *film*, only the film items are shown, perfect!

But now I want to make a complex filter by using filter groups. In both groups I want to use this genre filter. So I add another one. But for some reason this doesn't work, when I select *film* on both dropdowns and click apply it doesn't work anymore, and no results are given. I created a simplified view to test this. Here are images of my filter, and the use of it.

[This is my complex filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiMgr.png)

[Using one filter gives results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GGrP.png)

[But when selecting the *film* in both I get no result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSFcC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of my above question is a core bug. I added it to the Drupal Core issues, hope it will be solved soon. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2935113

In the mean time I found a work around. I use two different filters in the two added groups. Both filter on the same thing.

So in group 2, I filter on my Wat? field.

In group 3, I filter with the 'Has taxonomy filter'.

Both filter on the same taxonomy term but because they are different filters it does work now.